# Логирование через print

Tags: python, python-3.x

Время от времени вижу в проектах логирование через `print` по такому типу:

```
print('The action 1 has happened')
print('The action 2 has happened')
```

Далее просто через `cron` идет перенаправление потока вывода в какую-нибудь папку.

Запускаются они примерно так:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/user/project/venv/bin/python /home/user/project/script.py >> /home/user/project/logs/script.log
```

На сколько это разумно?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример перенаправления потока вывода, который в CRON'e.

Comment: @EgorSmolyakov сделал

Comment: Зачем? print это вывод не в файл, используйте [logging](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.html)

Comment: здесь нет объективного ответа. Исходя из принципа, что следует использовать самое простое решение, которое работает, то `print()` вполне подходит—просто и может работать даже когда более сложный код с logging, который пишет в файл, менее удобен, например, для `docker logs`.

Comment: @jfs если речь идет именно о логировании в файл, то не лучший вариант использовать `print()` для записи в файл, и тут очень хороши описаны плюсы logging:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918493/in-python-why-use-logging-instead-of-print

Comment: @users: нет, это вы додумали. Иначе следует заголовок вопроса изменить. `logging` конечно предоставляет больше гибкости (ERROR, DEBUG level), поэтому если вам нужны эти возможности, то нет смысла их самостоятельно переизобретать (и наружу их нельзя вынести (в стороннюю утилиту), так как только сам код определяет что error, что debug).

Comment: @jfs вы правы, скорее всего это зависит от проекта и задач, я для себя выбрал `logging`, но если это небольшой скрипт то перенаправлять вывод `print` в фай не плохой вариант.

Comment: Есть такое понятие как "Чистые функции"(из функционального программирования). Если применить термин к методам в парадигме ООП, то станет ясно, что явно разбросанные по коду print`ы делают методы менее "чистыми".

Comment: @jfs но ведь, если надо, чтобы запись была не в файл, то можно не показывать логгеру файл и вывод будет такой же как при `print`, но с кучей плюсов. Да и не сказать, что запись `logging.info('something')` намного сложнее, чем `print('something')`.

Comment: @faoxis: ещё раз: *"здесь нет объективного ответа"*. Обычно `logging.info` пишется как `logger.info`, [пример](https://gist.github.com/zed/01d629090110a4f95e2325521f5c4540). Недостаток по сравнению с print в том что чтобы ответить на вопрос "как мне этот вывод получить" в случае с logging количество вариантов конфигурации (зашито в коде, прописано в каком-то файле, передано с командной строки, задано в каком-то модуле ввиде плагина, итд) слишком большое--сложнее чем узнать куда stdout попадает.

Comment: если это скрипт на 20 строчек - то и print подойдет. Если это проект - то нужно использовать модуль logging. Это не только вывод в файл, а еще фильтрация и форматирование логов. Потом намного проще будет эти логи разобрать.  Если это библиотека - исключительно logging, иначе пользователи библиотеки вас проклянут. Есть еще интересный манифст https://12factor.net/ru/logs . Там говорят о том, что приложение должно всегда писать на stdout, а среда выполнения сама разберется что с этим делать, в какой файл записать, и как его ротировать

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вариант отлично подходит для решении вывода работы скрипта в файл.

---

Но если в дальнейшем появиться необходимость разделить вывод по типам: ошибка или информация и увеличить читаемость логов можно использовать [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.html) за место `print`.

Это позволит выводить сразу в файл и экран, есть возможность легко отследить когда был вывод и где.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

logger = None

def set_logging():
    global logger
    logger = logging.getLogger("main")
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(filename)s[%(lineno)-2d] %(levelname)-1s [%(asctime)s] %(message)s')
    file_logger = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler("adduser.log", maxBytes=10000000, backupCount=5)
    file_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file_logger.setFormatter(formatter)
    console_logger = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    console_logger.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(file_logger)
    logger.addHandler(console_logger)

set_logging()
logger.debug("DEBUG INFO")
logger.error("ERROR INFO")
logger.warning('WARNING INFO')
logger.info('INFO?')
```

Вывод:

```
test.py[21] DEBUG [2017-01-27 14:13:25,600] DEBUG INFO
test.py[22] ERROR [2017-01-27 14:13:25,601] ERROR INFO
test.py[23] WARNING [2017-01-27 14:13:25,601] WARNING INFO
test.py[24] INFO [2017-01-27 14:13:25,602] INFO?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# print удобен для чегото простого + делает перенос строки, берет несколько аргументов
for nums in [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]:
    print(*nums, file=open('file.txt', 'a'))
```